# How to find all possible combinations of adding two variables, each attached to a multiplier, summing up to a given number (cin)?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-c++

In my situation, a lorry has a capacity of 30, while a van has a capacity of 10. I need to find the number of vans/lorries needed to transport a given amount of cargo, say 100. I need to find all possible combinations of lorries + vans that will add up to 100.

The basic math calculation would be: (30*lorrycount) + (10*vancount) = n, where n is number of cargo.

**Output Example**

Cargo to be transported: 100

Number of Lorry: 0   3   2  1

Number of Van:   10  1   4  7

For example, the 2nd combination is 3 lorries, 1 van. Considering that lorries have capacity = 30 and van capacity = 10, (30*3)+(10*1) = 100 = n.

For now, we only have this code, which finds *literally* all combinations of numbers that add up to given number n, without considering the formula given above.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;

void findCombinationsUtil(int arr[], int index,
    int num, int reducedNum)
{
    int lorry_capacity = 30;
    int van_capacity = 10;
    // Base condition 
    if (reducedNum < 0)
        return;

    // If combination is found, print it 
    if (reducedNum == 0)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < index; i++)
            cout << arr[i] << " ";
        cout << endl;
        return;
    }

    // Find the previous number stored in arr[] 
    // It helps in maintaining increasing order 
    int prev = (index == 0) ? 1 : arr[index - 1];

    // note loop starts from previous number 
    // i.e. at array location index - 1 
    for (int k = prev; k <= num; k++)
    {
        // next element of array is k 
        arr[index] = k;

        // call recursively with reduced number 
        findCombinationsUtil(arr, index + 1, num,
            reducedNum - k);
    }
}


void findCombinations(int n)
{
    // array to store the combinations 
    // It can contain max n elements 
    std::vector<int> arr(n); // allocate  n elements

    //find all combinations 
    findCombinationsUtil(&*arr.begin(), 0, n, n);
}
int main()
{
    int n;
    cout << "Enter the amount of cargo you want to transport: ";
    cin >> n;
    cout << endl;
    //const int n = 10;
    findCombinations(n);

    return 0;
}
```

Do let me know if you have any solution to this, thank you.

Comment: Why is "1 lorry 8 vans" a solution? Shouldn't the capacity add up to exactly 100?

Comment: Also, are there any extensions to this problem you did not mention yet? Will the vehicle types become dynamic input later?

Comment: Is it always lorries and vans?

Comment: @acraig5075 exactly, not sure if the pasted combinations are user generated or expected

Comment: @Botje sorry, i have edited the combinations. no, there will be no more vehicle types. theres only vans and lorries. sorry for the mistake

Comment: I think you may be missing what _integer division_ and _modulus `%`_ can do for you. Research that and they will help you solve the problem in the simplest iterative way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An iterative way of finding all possible combinations

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector> 

int main()
{
    int cw = 100;
    int lw = 30, vw = 10;

    int maxl = cw/lw;  // maximum no. of lorries that can be there
    std::vector<std::pair<int,int>> solutions;    

    // for the inclusive range of 0 to maxl, find the corresponding no. of vans for each variant of no of lorries
    for(int l = 0; l<= maxl; ++l){
        bool is_integer = (cw - l*lw)%vw == 0; // only if this is true, then there is an integer which satisfies for given l

        if(is_integer){
            int v = (cw-l*lw)/vw; // no of vans
            solutions.push_back(std::make_pair(l,v));
        }
    }

    for( auto& solution : solutions){
        std::cout<<solution.first<<" lorries and "<< solution.second<<" vans" <<std::endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

We will create a recursive function that walks a global `capacities` array left to right and tries to load cargo into the various vehicle types. We keep track of how much we still have to load and pass that on to any recursive call. If we reach the end of the array, we produce a solution only if the remaining cargo is zero.

```
std::vector<int> capacities = { 30, 10 };
using Solution = std::vector<int>;
using Solutions = std::vector<Solution>;

void tryLoad(int remaining_cargo, int vehicle_index, Solution so_far, std::back_insert_iterator<Solutions>& solutions) {
    if (vehicle_index == capacities.size()) {
        if (remaining_cargo == 0) // we have a solution
            *solutions++ = so_far;
        return;
    }
    int capacity = capacities[vehicle_index];
    for (int vehicles = 0; vehicles <= remaining_cargo / capacity; vehicles++) {
        Solution new_solution = so_far;
        new_solution.push_back(vehicles);
        tryLoad(remaining_cargo - vehicles * capacity, vehicle_index + 1, new_solution, solutions);
    }
}
```

Calling this as follows should produce the desired output in `all_solutions`:

```
Solutions all_solutions;
auto inserter = std::back_inserter(all_solutions)
tryLoad(100, 0, Solution{}, inserter);
```

Comment: i ran the program and theres no output

Comment: You need to print the contents of `all_solutions` to actually get output. It is a `std::vector<std::vector<int>>` so you will need a doubly-nested `for` loop.